# Know that a ViewController appears because of a Dismissal (not segue)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, segue, dismiss

I'm trying to figure out how to grab a class that just dismissed itself, inside my rootViewController. I have several options to dismiss back to my rootViewController and I need to know if it came from one instance in order to change a bit of UI accordingly.

I'm looking for something similar to `[self presentingViewController]` except for when the viewController appears because of a dismissal and not a segue. Is there a built in method for grabbing this?

Comment: not very clear what you want. maybe you can check these methods: `isMovingFromParentViewController`, `isMovingToParentViewController`, `isBeingDismissed` and `isBeingPresented`

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a segue? An unwind segue would be great for the is, because you can get the sourceViewController property of the segue being performed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically fixed this problem by keeping track of whether I even visit the one view controller I was concerned about dismissing from. That way, I just set a property in the viewController before I segue so I already know when I return that I need to take care of the UI changes. Thank you for the comments on unwind segues. I will definitely be implementing them in the future very soon!

Answer (score 1):

*update*

Everything in this answer is old news - since XCode 4.5 we can use unwind segues to get back to any previous viewController and trigger an unwind method in that controller. (thanks @rdelmar)

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-to-use-them)

---

*the old way/code way.. which ideally involves delegates to get specific methods implemented*

When a class dismisses itself, you can't grab it because it is ... dismissed. You need to have a hold of it *before* it is dismissed, and then know about the dismissing.

Elaborating on this a little, classes don't usually dismiss themselves, their owning classes do the dismissing. The obfuscating method here could be the UIViewController method:

```
- (void) dismissViewControllerAnimated:
```

which is a shorthand for

```
- (void) [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:nil]
```

The presenting viewController has a property `presentedViewController` which holds on to that dismissed object - until it is dismissed. When the presentingViewController dismisses, it resets it's `presentedViewController` property to nil. But you always have the option of copying that reference into another (strong/retained) property prior to, and interrogating it after, the dismissing event.

To quote apple:

> "If you want to retain a reference to the receiver’s presented view controller, get the value in the presentedViewController property before calling [ dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
>    ]."